# Using HttpClient to auto submit document

Tags: java, html, httpclient

I am using Apache HttpClient to fetch data from a webservice. Instead of getting the JSON response, I am getting a response which has a document.autosubmit.submit(); Is HttpClient capable of handling this automatically? or should I send the submit using httpclient again ?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume that the response you are getting has `document.autosubmit.submit()` in JavaScript where `autosubmit` is the name of the form.

If that is the case, no, HTTPClient is not capable of executing the JavaScript. Its worth looking at http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ which does browser emulation.